# How do I determine if a managed metadata group is for a site collection or not using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata

I am iterating through managed metadata using CSOM and PowerShell against SharePoint Online.  I need to know if a managed metadata group is a site collection group or if it is global.  When I use the following script to make that determination, it always responds with IsSiteCollectionGroup is false even though I know one of my groups is a site collection group.  Am I missing something?

```
Add-Type -Path C:\SPClientLib\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
Add-Type -Path C:\SPClientLib\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
Add-Type -Path C:\SPClientLib\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll

$url = Read-Host -Prompt "SPO Url"
$user = Read-Host -Prompt "user"
$pwd = Read-Host -Prompt "pwd" -AsSecureString
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($user,$pwd)
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
$ctx.Credentials = $creds

$mms = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($ctx)
$ctx.Load($mms)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$termstores = $mms.TermStores
$ctx.Load($termstores)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$termstore = $termstores[0]
$ctx.Load($termstore)

$groups = $termstore.Groups
$ctx.Load($groups)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

foreach ($group in $groups)
{
    $ctx.Load($group)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    #$ctx.Load($group.IsSiteCollectionGroup) # tried loading IsSiteCollectionGroup explicitly, but that gives an error
    #$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host "Group Name:" $group.Name "(site collection group? $($group.IsSiteCollectionGroup))"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script works for me, but it is pretty similar to your version:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy")


Function Get-SPOContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    return $context
}



$UserName = "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"


$ctx = Get-SPOContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
$taxSession = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($ctx)

$termStore = $taxSession.GetDefaultKeywordsTermStore()
$groups = $termStore.Groups
$ctx.Load($groups)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

foreach ($group in $groups)
{
    Write-Host "Group Name:" $group.Name "(Site Group: $($group.IsSiteCollectionGroup))"
}
```

### What to verify?

1)Ensure the compatible version ([version 16](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)) of `SharePoint Client Components SDK` is used

2)Ensure site collection group really exist, for that purpose you could utilize the following script:

```
$taxSession = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($ctx)
$termStore = $taxSession.GetDefaultKeywordsTermStore()
$termGroup = $termStore.GetSiteCollectionGroup($ctx.Site,$true) //create site collection term group if it doesn't exist
$termStore.CommitAll()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Vadim.  Your script works, but it turns out mine does as well.  I wasn't looking at something properly.  Thanks for your time.